# Expanding and calling backend Service in UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have a UI Grid configured for my site. I have used expandableRowTemplate to expand it to show some simple content when user clicks on the expand button. Right now it shows the content properly.

But my requirement is when user user clicks on the expand button apart from expanding and showing the content it should also call a backend service to send some data to server and receive something.

Is this scenario possible in UI Grid? I am using Angular 1.5 and Ui Grid 4.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

There's public API event which is fired when a row is toggled.
You can provide a function calling the REST service to this event.

```
   gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged(scope,function(row){})
```

And if you want to make a call only if the row is expanded, I see only 2 ways:

1. Either you have your own one redundant key to each row as **row.isExpanded** and toggle it inside this function and use for your purpose.
2. Or you can find if row inside this function is included in getExpandedRows()'s result. This is hilariously redundant.

Source: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.expandable.api:PublicApi

Comment: Harshali-  So you are trying to tell me that I have to add my rest calling code  in rowExpandedBeforeStateChanged: function(scope,row){}   this method which is there in ui-grid.js?

Comment: Yes. From what I understand from your Question, this should work for you.